# How to make all checkboxes unchecked with a certain condition? Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 45 check boxes that you can check. What I want to do is if  you try to select more than 6 check boxes it will automatically disable all the buttons, however, if you tap the even one of the checked  checkbox ,it will make all the checkbox checkable. This sounds simple ,but I cannot implements this method. I would be grateful if the pros here can help a noob like me. Here is the sample code.

```
            checkbox[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) { buttonView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); 

                    buttonClicked.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                    buttonView.setTextSize(18);

                    count+=1;

                    if(count>=6){

                        for(int i = 0; i< 43;i++){

                         checkbox[i].setEnabled(false);
                         stopped =  checkbox[i].isChecked();
                         if(stopped==true){
                             for(int a = 0; a < checkbox.length;a++){
                                 checkbox[a].setEnabled(true);
                             }
                             }



                        }

                    }
                    }
                    if (!isChecked) {buttonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 

                        buttonClicked.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                         buttonView.setTextSize(15);
                         count-=1;
```

Comment: you can do this by creating an integer variable. Initially give it 0 and increase its value when any `Checkbox` gets checked and decrease when it gets unchecked using i++ or i--.

Comment: But I wonder  how to checkbox[a].setEnabled(true)  all the checkboxes ? I cannot find a way to make all the checkboxes clickable. I'm making checkboxes out of loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is your reaction to finding a checked checkbox. We need to look at removing the internal loop under `if(stopped==true)`(Note 2). 
You simply need

```
if(stopped){
    checkbox[i].setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then in your `if(!isChecked)`(Note 3) you add your loop back in to reenable all the checkboxes so it will look like

```
if(!isChecked){
//your existing code
    for(int i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
        checkbox[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** I would advise that you swap your hardcoded "43"to checkbox.length just to keep things cleaner.

**Note 2:** You don't need to put ==true, it's already a boolean so this can just be if(stopped)

**Note 3:** This is what "else" was designed for. if(...){} if(!...){} is synonymous with if(...){}else{}.

**Note 4:** To void unnecessary looping (always good practice) we should maybe add another check here before the for loop to ensure that there were 6 boxes active.

```
if(count>=6){
    for(int i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
        checkbox[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}
count--;
```

**Note 5:** `x+=1;` can be replaced by `x++;` and similarly for `x-=1;` `x--;`(as said in the comments to your question)